# call javascript page function inside ajaxed html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where i use jQuery to load some content into a div element

```
<div id="contents-box-in"></div>
```

jQuery code in page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#contents-box-in").load("new-01.php", function() {               
            $('#contents-box-in').fadeIn(120);              
        });

        var updateBoxData = function(data) {

            $('#contents-box-in').fadeOut(100, function() {
                $('#contents-box-in').html(data).fadeIn(130);
            });

        }

    });
```

the content that i load is a form that needs to load a new page sending collected data from form

```
            $('#form-buttons-next').click(function(e) {

                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

                var formS = $.ajax({
                    url         : 'new-02.php',
                    type        : 'POST',                   
                    data        : formData,
                    async       : false,
                    cache       : false,
                    processData : false,
                    contentType : false
                });

                formS.done(function(data) {

                   if (data != null) {

                        updateBoxData(data);

                    }

                });

                formS.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

                    alert("error");

                });

            });
```

since i do this in different step i would like to use a shared function contained in page that is loading the ajax content but i get updateBoxData is undefined

I guess that ajaxed content can't see parent container function

The easy way would be to load a different .js file containing shared function, i was wondering if is possible to access the updateBoxData from ajaxed contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `updateBoxData` is defined inside a callback function you passed to `.ready` and hence its scope is limited to that function. Let us call this callback function Fx.

The click handler (the function passed to `.click` in the second part), which we call it Fy is defined outside of Fx and as a result does not have access to the variables defined in Fx (remember `updateBoxData` is a variable inside Fx).

That is why your code does not work. To get it working simply take `updateBoxData` out of the callback in `.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contents-box-in").load("new-01.php", function() {               
        $('#contents-box-in').fadeIn(120);              
    });
});
function updateBoxData(data) {
    $('#contents-box-in').fadeOut(100, function() {
        $('#contents-box-in').html(data).fadeIn(130);
    });
}
...
```

The rest is the same.

Answer (score 3):

> ...i would like to use a shared function contained in page that is loading the ajax content but i get `updateBoxData` is undefined
>
> I guess that ajaxed content can't see parent container function

No, that's not why. Your `updateBoxData` variable is scoped to the function it's declared in (your `ready`) callback. If you want it accessible globally, you'll need to make it global instead.

The problem is, though, the global namespace is already *incredibly crowded*. So if you put all of your useful functions there as globals, you're going to run into conflicts sooner or later.

For that reason, for now until browsers support ES2015 modules (which will take a while), I suggest giving yourself just **one** global symbol, something unlikely to conflict with other things, and assigning an object to it with properties for your various utility functions. E.g.:

```
var MyNiftyUtils = {
    updateBoxData: function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then you call that via `MyNiftyUtils.updateBoxData`. If the verbosity bothers you, no worries, just use a scoping function and assign it to a local:

```
(function() {
    var u = MyNiftyUtils;

    // ....
    u.updateBoxData(/*...*/);
})();
```

(There are about 18 variations on that theme, this is just one of them.)

Comment: i'm so dumb and so used to jQuery i did not notice i was inside document ready i  will accept Ali since is more related to fix the issue even if your answer add some great suggestions.

Comment: @al404IT: You're welcome to accept any answer you choose. :-) I will just point out that that's what I said to do: Make it a global, not a local to the `ready` callback.